# Looking for a Portuguese translated Tanakh

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, translation

I am looking for a Portuguese translated Tanakh?
My brother in law wishes to explore Torah and is Brazilian by background. I would like to help him read in his native tongue to understand.
Thank you!

Comment: I see on the Portuguese Chabad website that they have translations of [Psalms](https://pt.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1090063/jewish/Tehilim-Portugus.htm) and [Esther](https://pt.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1090123/jewish/Traduo-da-Meguilat-Ester.htm), but I don't see the rest. If you want something in print, it looks like there are plenty of options when googling "tanah portugues".

Comment: @magicker72 But buyer beware, e.g. you do not want this https://www.amazon.com.br/B%C3%ADblia-Judaica-Completa-V%C3%A1rios-Autores/dp/8000001454.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Meir and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

1. [Bíblia Hebraica](https://www.amazon.com.br/B%C3%ADblia-Hebraica-David-Gorodovits-ebook/dp/B077BFMBRL/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=1RNE4C5K1HZER&keywords=biblia%20hebraica&qid=1636988099&s=books&sprefix=biblia%20he%2Cstripbooks%2C278&sr=1-2) (The entire Tanach translated in ligh of
   Talmudic and midrashic sources).
2. [Tanah Completo - Hebraico e Português](https://www.amazon.com.br/Tanah-Completo-Azul-Jairo-Fridlin/dp/8579310075/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2U3RALM35QDGQ&keywords=tanah%20completo%20-%20hebraico%20e%20portugu%C3%AAs&qid=1636987711&s=books&sprefix=tanah%2Cstripbooks%2C272&sr=1-2&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.6a09f7ec-d911-4889-ad70-de8dd83c8a74) (updated translation of the previous one, in ligh of
   Talmudic and midrashic sources).
3. [Torá: a lei de Moisés](https://www.amazon.com.br/Tor%C3%A1-Mois%C3%A9s-Meir-Matzliah-Melamed/dp/8585583266/ref=sr_1_10?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2U3RALM35QDGQ&keywords=tanah%20completo%20-%20hebraico%20e%20portugu%C3%AAs&qid=1636987711&s=books&sprefix=tanah%2Cstripbooks%2C272&sr=1-10&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.6a09f7ec-d911-4889-ad70-de8dd83c8a74) by Meir Matzliah Melamed.
4. [Torá Rashi - Nova Coleção](https://www.amazon.com.br/Tor%C3%A1-Rashi-Nova-Cole%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Shlomo-Yitschaki/dp/8579031524/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=KS3HVLGRGK5R&keywords=tora%20rashi&qid=1636987735&s=books&sprefix=tora%20%2Cstripbooks%2C269&sr=1-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.25548f35-0de7-44b3-b28e-0f56f3f96147) (Torah with Rashi).
5. [A Torá Viva](https://www.amazon.com.br/Tor%C3%A1-Viva-5%C2%AA-Ed-2018/dp/8579030617/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=tora%20viva&qid=1636987784&s=books&sr=1-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.6a09f7ec-d911-4889-ad70-de8dd83c8a74) (translation of The living Torah, by Aryeh Kaplan).

Comment: Chumash Gutnick 
by Chaim Miller is also available in Portuguese

Comment: Plus Chumash by Moshe Wisnefsky which is really the Kehot Chumash Edition but without the commentaries that the English one has, just with the interpolated translation and an introduction to each parashah

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help, if has access to internet.

[image: sefaria_portuguese_torah]

[https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.1?ven=BJC_-_[pt]&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.1?ven=BJC_-_%5Bpt%5D&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en)

Comment: This has only Genesis chapter 1 as of Sep. 2021.

Answer (score -2):

As there seems to be a lack of Jewish translations, the following are Christian Bibles but they may be useful so long as one keeps that in mind and that they may contain some non-Judaic renderings.

1. The translation of the Bible by the Christian pastor [João Ferreira de Almeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo%C3%A3o_Ferreira_de_Almeida) (1819) is available in many places such as

- https://www.bibliatodo.com/pt/a-biblia/versao/Joao-ferreira-de-almeida-atualizada
- https://archive.org/details/bibliajoaoferreiradealmeidajacobusopdenakker1819/page/n3/mode/2up

2. There is a "Brasilian Translation of the Bible" (1917) by Dr. H. C. Tucker et. al. 
   The translators are also Christian.
   Tradução Brasileira da Bíblia
   https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Brasileira_da_B%C3%ADblia

Gênesis 1:1
*No princípio criou Deus o céu e a terra.*

Comment: Giving a recommendation to someone looking to find out more about the Tanach of a Christian translation of the Old Testament of the Bible is extremely dangerous. Christian translations are not Tanach, and are pushing a Jesus narrative. Please remove this.

Comment: @Yehuda "extremely" dangerous in my opinion no.  Danger is everywhere.  "In the way a person wants to go, that's where he's lead."  For someone already leaning toward Judaism and Tanakh who needs basic literal meaning of the words I think this is useful, especially in the apparent absence of a free and Judaic translation.   Christian and Jesus-skewed biases in Christian Bibles are generally very few and are easily questioned and easily refuted.

Comment: @Yehuda However in regard to that danger I've added and clarified a caveat.

Comment: sefer.com.br will ship to anywhere in the world so it's possible to use Jewish sources in Portuguese!